# How to show different Navbars based on authentication status and role?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, navbar

So my problem here is that I don't want the login and signup tabs to be able to see the rest of the navigation unless the user authenticates. After the authentication I want to show user a subset of these tabs depending on the role that they have. however, when i tried conditional Navbar, the rendering wouldn't happen unless I refresh. I'm pretty new to react development so any easy workaround will be appreciated.
My Goal is to get a login/signup page which will let user see the navbar components based on their role. Thank in advance.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="container mt-2" style={{ marginTop: 40 }}>
        <Switch>
          <Route path= "/login">
            <Login/>
          </Route>
          
          <Route path="/addStock">
            <Stock />
          </Route>

          <Route path='/addSector'>
            <Sector />
          </Route>

          <Route path='/manageSector'>
            <ManageSector />
          </Route>

          <Route path="/addCompany">
            <Company />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/uploadSheet">
            <Data />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/manageCompanies">
            <ManageCompanies />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/addIPO">
            <IPO />
          </Route>

          <Route path="/manageIPO">
            <ManageIPO />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/stockexchange">
            <StockExchange />
          </Route>

          <Route path="/managestockexchange">
            <ManageStockExchange />
          </Route>

          <Route path="/signup">
            <SignUp />
          </Route>

          <Route path="/comparisonCharts">
            <ComparisonCharts />
          </Route>
        </Switch>

      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Comment: How are you storing your auth state in your app?

Comment: Take a look at 'PrivateRoute' component example in the react-router-dom docs https://reactrouter.com/native/example/auth-workflow

Comment: I am locally storing the jwt token: localStorage.setItem("token", myJson.token) and auth state is basically checked by looking for the token: isAuth = !!localStorage.getItem("token");

Answer (score 0):

React updates pages only if any state changed. In your page you can use useState hook or if you use redux/mobx etc... in your app, you can write your user data to your store and listen user data state in the page. The first option useState hook code is like this

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const login = (userData) => {
   const response = fetch()... //Call your api here
if(response === true)
   setIsLoggedIn(response)
  }
  return (
<BrowserRouter>
  
  <div className="container mt-2" style={{ marginTop: 40 }}>
    <Switch><Navbar />
      {isLoggedIn && <Route path= "/login">
        <Login/>
      </Route>}
      
      <Route path="/addStock">
        <Stock />
      </Route>

      <Route path='/addSector'>
        <Sector />
      </Route>

      <Route path='/manageSector'>
        <ManageSector />
      </Route>

      <Route path="/addCompany">
        <Company />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/uploadSheet">
        <Data />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/manageCompanies">
        <ManageCompanies />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/addIPO">
        <IPO />
      </Route>

      <Route path="/manageIPO">
        <ManageIPO />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/stockexchange">
        <StockExchange />
      </Route>

      <Route path="/managestockexchange">
        <ManageStockExchange />
      </Route>

      <Route path="/signup">
        <SignUp />
      </Route>

      <Route path="/comparisonCharts">
        <ComparisonCharts />
      </Route>
    </Switch>

  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: While I understand that updating the state would get the page to re render, I don't exactly understand how I invoke a method in App component using the login button in <Login/> component. Would you please explain?

Comment: Its just an example, there must be better way to do this. Nevertheless if you want to apply, pass login method to the <Login /> component.

**In App component**

`<Login loginMethod={login} />`

**In Login component**

`return(... <Button onClick={() => this.props.loginMethod(userData)} />)`

So you can call your parent component's methods with this way.